# Conditional Probability for a coin to be fair

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

A gambler has in his pocket a fair coin and a biased coin which will land heads with probability $\frac34$.
He selects one of the coins at random; when he tosses it, it lands heads.
What is the probability it is the fair coin?
(II)If he tosses the same coin a second time, and again it lands heads. What now
is the probability it is the fair coin?
(III) If he tosses the same coin for a third time, and this time it lands tails. What now is the probability it is the fair coin?

---

My solution using Bayes:

(I)$$P(\text{fair}|\text{heads})=\frac{P(\text{fair}\cap\text{heads})}{P(\text{heads})}=\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac12}{\frac12\cdot\frac12+\frac12\cdot\frac34}=\frac{\frac14}{\frac58}=\frac25$$

(II)
$$P(\text{fair}|\text{heads,heads})=\frac{P(\text{fair}\cap\text{heads}\cap\text{heads})}{P(\text{heads}\cap\text{heads})}=\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12}{\frac12\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12+\frac12\cdot\frac34\cdot\frac34}=\frac{4}{13}$$

(III)
$$P(\text{fair}|\text{heads,heads,Tails})=\frac{P(\text{fair}\cap\text{heads}\cap\text{heads}\cap\text{tails})}{P(\text{heads}\cap\text{heads}\cap\text{tails})}=\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12}{\frac12\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12+\frac12\cdot\frac34\cdot\frac34\cdot\frac14}=\frac{8}{17}$$
Please can someone help me if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Alternatively notice that if the probabilities of the two coins landing on heads are pooled, the fair coin has 2/5 of the "share".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Please can someone help me if my understanding is correct.

No, you have *correctly* employed Bayes' Rule and the Law of Total Probability to arrive at the *correct* answer, so there is *nothing left* to help you with.

Good work.

Comment: @rowang Second verse, same as the first.  There's no question; you've got this down okay.  $\color{green}\checkmark$  (Assuming the repeat of $(1/4)/(5/8)$ to be a cut and paste typo.)

Comment: edited the typo. Thanks. I was not sure if my application was right.